# Optimization in complex vector space

Tags: cv.complex-variables, global-optimization

I am trying to solve the following question
$$ \max_{  \mathbf{w}\in\mathbb{C}^N } \ f(\gamma)$$
$$\textrm{s.t.}  \ \gamma=a|\mathbf{h}^H\mathbf{w}|^2$$
$$\|\mathbf{w}\|^2\leq b,$$
$$|\mathbf{g}_{k}^H\mathbf{w}|^2 \leq \delta, \ k\in\{1,...,K\},$$
where $f$ is a non-decreasing function and $\mathbb{C}^N$ is the set of complex vectors. Both $\mathbf{h}$ and $\mathbf{g}_k$ are complex vectors and $a$ is real.

By Cauchy-Schwarz, we have $|\mathbf{h}^H\mathbf{w}|^2\leq \|\mathbf{h}\|^2 \|\mathbf{w}\|^2$, and the inequality becomes an equality iff $\mathbf{w}=\alpha\mathbf{h}$ for some $\alpha\in\mathbb{C}$. Then, to optimize $\alpha$, I set it to $\alpha^*=\min\big( (\frac{\delta}{\max_k |\mathbf{g}_{k}^H\mathbf{h}|^2})^{1/2}, (\frac{b}{\|\mathbf{h}\|^2})^{1/2} \big)$. This gives a feasible solution. But how do I prove that this is the optimal solution? I tried contradiction but it didn't go anywhere.

Edit: I have tried the following. For contradiction, suppose there exists $\mathbf{w}'\neq \mathbf{w}:=\alpha^*\mathbf{h}$ such that $\gamma(\mathbf{w})<\gamma(\mathbf{w}')$. We have
$$\gamma(\mathbf{w})=a(\alpha^*)^2\|\mathbf{h}\|^4 < \gamma(\mathbf{w}')=a|\mathbf{h}\mathbf{w}|^2\leq a\|\mathbf{h}\|^2\|\mathbf{w}\|^2 \leq ab\|\mathbf{h}\|^2$$
Hence,
$$(\alpha^*)^2\|\mathbf{h}\|^2<b.$$
This means that the condition $\gamma(\mathbf{w})<\gamma(\mathbf{w}')$ can hold if
$$(\frac{\delta}{\max_k |\mathbf{g}_{k}^H\mathbf{h}|^2})^{1/2} < (\frac{b}{\|\mathbf{h}\|^2})^{1/2}. \ \ (*)$$
In that case, $\mathbf{w}=(\frac{\delta}{\max_k |\mathbf{g}_{k}^H\mathbf{h}|^2})^{1/2} \mathbf{h}$ and
$\gamma(\mathbf{w})= a (\frac{\delta}{\max_k |\mathbf{g}_{k}^H\mathbf{h}|^2})\|\mathbf{h}\|^4$. For $\gamma( \mathbf{w}')> \gamma( \mathbf{w})$, we must have
$$\gamma(\mathbf{w})= a (\frac{\delta}{\max_k |\mathbf{g}_{k}^H\mathbf{h}|^2})\|\mathbf{h}\|^4 <\gamma( \mathbf{w}')=a|\mathbf{h}\mathbf{w}'|^2 $$
or
$$ (\frac{\delta}{\max_k |\mathbf{g}_{k}^H\mathbf{h}|^2})\|\mathbf{h}\|^4 < |\mathbf{h}\mathbf{w}'|^2 \leq \|\mathbf{h}\|^2\|\mathbf{w}'\|^2 $$
or
$$ (\frac{\delta}{\max_k |\mathbf{g}_{k}^H\mathbf{h}|^2})\|\mathbf{h}\|^2 <  \|\mathbf{w}'\|^2 $$

Comment: I have also posted this question on math.stackexchange. I don’t know if it’s against the rules here or not.